# Proper use of JQuery async calls while creating a new object in a knockout array?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have a list of documents in my web application.  I allow the user to create new documents.  When they click "new", a strictly client-side instance of a document shortcut shows up with a blank title field in focus.  They then input a title and click save.  In the viewmodel, this is what save does:

```
var document = new documentViewModel(dataservice.createDocument(newData)); // calls ajax method below with new document's data to POST back
innerModel.documents.remove(item);
innerModel.documents.push(document);
```

I remove the placeholder document (`item`) and push the new, real-data `document`.  But as it stands, document is just a blank item that gets pushed before the real data from the async call gets back, so no real data gets pushed.

`Save` sends a jquery call to the endpoint:

```
   var options = {
            url: saveEndpoint,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: newDocument,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            }
        };

        return $.ajax(options)
            .done(function (response) {
                return response;
            })
            .fail(function (msg) {
                toastr.error("Error: Could not create document.");
            });
```

As it stands, this is not working because the real data never makes its way to the view.

What is the standard approach to using async calls to create new items in this fashion?  Should I make it a synchronous call?  Or is there a middle ground that I'm not aware of?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dataservice is improperly handling the ajax calls.  `$.ajax()` doesn't return the results of the request, you need to pass a callback method to it so it knows what to do when the request is completed.

`dataservice.createDocument` should look like:

```
createDocument(newDocument, handleResponse) {
    var options = {
        url: saveEndpoint,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: newDocument,
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    };

    $.ajax(options)
        .done(function (response) {
            // this is the callback method that gets passed in
            handleResponse(response);
        })
        .fail(function (msg) {
            toastr.error("Error: Could not create document.");
        });
}
```

and called like this:

```
// the function in the argument is the callback method that will be executed
// when the ajax request is completed
dataservice.createDocument(newData, function (document) {
    var document = new documentViewModel(document);
    innerModel.documents.remove(item);
    innerModel.documents.push(document); 
});
```

see these other questions for some more examples and explanation:

- [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call?lq=1)